# Create data validation unique items for Drop Down list without intermediate data and without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of names and I want to make a drop-down list with unique names for data validation. I created a drop down list now that list is showing name but same names multiple times.

Is there a way to create a drop down list with unique names **without intermediate data and without VBA**? Only using formulas in Excel 2019 or 2021.

[image]

Surprisingly, this task in Office 365 is solved by default.

[UPDATE]
I apologize to everyone if I misled someone, the Microsoft Office version in which everything works by default in the Microsoft Store has an installation version of 18.2205.1091.0 and looks like this
[image]

[ADDED]
Maybe someone knows how to implement the idea of an Evil Blue Monkey? (@EvilBlueMonkey)

Comment: Do you have `UNIQUE()` function on Excel 2021.

Comment: @Harun24hr I tried using the `UNIQUE()` function, but I get an error when creating a drop-down list. Is there a secret?

Comment: You can't use `UNIQUE()` function directly on validation list. You need to put it on a cell and then refer that cell using `#` operator. Suppose you put `UNIQUE()` function to `C1` cell then use `=C1#` to data validation list.

Comment: @Harun24hr Thanks for the explanation, there is no error with this format. But it turns out we are creating an additional list. My question is how to do it without additional lists and intermediate data.

Comment: I think, may be not possible.

Comment: @Harun24hr is correct: a list-based data validation must refer to an actual range within the worksheet or else be hard-coded as a comma-separated list.

Comment: Maybe create a name with a UNIQUE funtion and then refer to that for the data validation? Can't really test it because i don't have UNIQUE in my Excel.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey this is an interesting idea and such a solution would suit me. I created a new name `names=UNIQUE($A$2:$A$10)` as you recommended. But when I try to specify it for data validation, I get an error. The variant in the format `=names#` also does not pass.

Comment: I've too tried to create a name-based solution, but no luck so far. Still i don't see any other option if you can't use neither VBA nor extra cells.

Comment: Can you clarify your statement "*Surprisingly, this task in Office 365 is solved by default.*"? As far as I was aware, there is still no solution in O365. See my previous comment: "*a list-based data validation must refer to an actual range within the worksheet or else be hard-coded as a comma-separated list.*" This still stands for O365.

Comment: @JosWoolley in Office 365, it is enough to specify a range of cells in the data validation and the drop-down list is immediately formed only from unique values.

Comment: My recommendation is to violate the condition of 
> ...without intermediate data...
I have investigated doing this with different formulas and unique() and could not get it to work otherwise.

Comment: @AnyDozer Can you clarify your last statement? How precisely do I achieve what you say? I have Office 365. I typed "A", "B", "B", "B", "C" into the range `E1:E5` then, in cell `A1`, added a Data Validation List with reference `=$E$1:$E$5`. My dropdown does not contain unique values only - I still see "B" three times.

Comment: @JosWoolley I'll answer you in a few days, I don't have Office 365 right now.

Comment: @JosWoolley look I have updated the content of my question. In data validation, I point to cells `=A2:A10` and that's it.

Comment: @AnyDozer Look at your picture again. Jack and Thomas still appear twice in the dropdown, just as per the range referenced. Suggest you remove that from your post.

Comment: @JosWoolley this screen belongs to version 2021.

Comment: @AnyDozer So show us some proof that you can get a unique list as you suggested.

Comment: @JosWoolley the best proof will be if you install the version specified for you and do it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation is to violate the condition of

> ...without intermediate data...

If you don't like my answer don't check it as a solution. I have investigated doing this with different formulas and unique() and could not get it to work otherwise. Violating this condition might be the key to the solution. Here are my steps to the solution as I would do it.

1. Develop the list in on Sheet1 column A
2. Create a new sheet call it **Hidden** (or what you want).
3. In cell A2 of **Hidden** create the formula `=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A10000,Sheet1!A2:A10000<>"")))`. I use sort because the data looks nicer that way. I use filter to remove the blank cells. This filter also allows for more cells to be included. Unique provides just one instance when there is a duplicate.
4. In Cell A1 create a name for list like `Name_List`. Then create a Defined Name for cells A1 through A100 or the limit you want. Choose Name from top cell.
5. Hide the **Hidden** sheet. There are 2 levels of hidden. The first level is right click on sheet tab and choose `Hide`. If you want **Very Hidden** then hit the keys *Alt-F11* then change the properties for sheet 2 to very hidden (see image).[image]
6. Save the workbook as .xlsx extension.
7. Back on Sheet1 choose a cell for the dropdown list using *data validation*. Choose List and enter `=Name_List`

Please note done without VBA.

Comment: Shane, this is not the solution I wanted to get. But this is the best offer. I appeal once again to everyone, if you offer a better solution, you will receive the same bounty.

Comment: Shane and another question, is how to get back a very hidden sheet?

Comment: @AnyDozer, To get back to the very hidden sheet hit the keys *Alt-F11* to change the visibility again to `-1 - xlSheetVisible`. You change change the visibility as much as you want. The nice thing about very hidden is when you share it with other people they will not normally find it.