# Excel: How do I create unique Data Validation List (Drop Down) using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I create a list of unique character in the data validation dialog box?
When I try to create the drop down list in cell (C,2). I get "Source currently evaluates to error" message. How do I fix that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `UNIQUE()` will not work in Data Validation, you need helper columns and please search `Stackoverflow` this has been solved earlier. use the same `UNIQUE()` function in a different column and use the column as a reference in data validation. so in source validation it will be like =D2# assuming you have placed the unique spill array in `D2` cell

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any other code/formula apart from Unique that can create unique dynamic list in data validation dialog box?

Comment: May be using with `VBA` -- but I am not quite sure, I am trying to find some from `SO` it may find useful for your need. with formula you need some some intermediary column for sure. thats definite.

Comment: found one, not personally tested but you can try this is using `VBA` [Insert list of unique values in data-validation-list (without using a helper column)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75433367/8162520)

Comment: You can check this one as well, very unique approach [Create data validation unique items for Drop Down list without intermediate data and without VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73044904/8162520)

Comment: I think you will find using `=UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,B:B<>""))` in a helper column that you hide way off on the right of the sheet.  The easiest way.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir adding one `SORT()` funciton makes it more elegant  - Sir or instead of `FILTER()` --> `SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(B:B,1)))`